# How to edit received email increase the font size and display Print Preview

Tags: vba, outlook

Outlook 2016 seems to offer no possibility to change the text size when printing HTML Mails,I would like to solve the problem with a macro.

It should:

1. Open the selected message.
2. Change the format to HTML (for plain text mails (even if the text size would be adjustable for those mails)).
3. Goes into the edit mode.
4. Select the whole text.
5. Increase the font size (x times).
6. Shows the print dialog.

Here's the little bit I've figured out so far:

```
Sub test()
    ActiveExplorer.Selection(1).Display
    ActiveExplorer.Selection(1).BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
    ActiveInspector.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "EditMessage"
    SendKeys "^(a)"
    SendKeys "^+(<)"
    SendKeys "^+(<)"
    SendKeys "^+(<)"
    SendKeys "^+(<)"
    SendKeys "%(du)"
End Sub
```

It works, but I am not really happy with it.

Any Idea how I could do the steps 4-6 without SendKeys?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    Dim olMsg As Object
    Set olMsg = ActiveExplorer.selection.Item(1)

    Dim Email As Outlook.MailItem
    If TypeOf olMsg Is MailItem Then
       Set Email = olMsg

       If Email.BodyFormat <> olFormatHTML Then
          Email.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
          Email.Body = "<font size=" & "30" & ">" & Email.Body & "</font>"
          Email.Save
          Email.Display
          ActiveInspector.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "FilePrintPreview"
       End If

    End If
End Sub
```